# Why is the variance of this random variable one?

Tags: expected-value, variance

I stumbled across the following problem in the paper "STOCHASTIC SPANNING TREE PROBLEM" of Ishii.
There is a random variable defined by
$$
\frac{\sum_j (c_j x_j - \mu_jx_j)}{(\sum_j\sigma_j^2x_j^2)^{1/2}},
$$
where each $c_j$ is distributed according to a normal distribution with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_j^2$. It is said that this variable is distributed according to the standard normal distribution and I try to proof this for myself.

For the expected value I get zero, just by using its linearity and then the sums in the numerator cancel out.
Now to the variance: I try to use the property that $\text{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) - (\mathbb{E}(X))^2$ where I already know that the second term is zero.
Then I square the fraction and aim to get a nominator that cancels out to one with the denominator. Since the denominator is constant I drag it out of the expected value and get
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(  \sum_j (c_j x_j) - \sum_j(\mu_jx_j)  \right)^2 \right]}{\sum_j\sigma_j^2x_j^2}
$$
which I expand to
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(  \sum_j c_j x_j \right)^2  -2 \left(  \sum_j c_j x_j \right)\left(  \sum_j \mu_j x_j \right) + \left(\sum_j\mu_jx_j  \right)^2 \right]}{\sum_j\sigma_j^2x_j^2}
$$
where I again use the linearity of the expected value to get
$$
\frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(  \sum_j c_j x_j \right)^2 \right] - \left(\sum_j\mu_jx_j  \right)^2}{\sum_j\sigma_j^2x_j^2} = \frac{\mathbb{E} \left[ \left(  \sum_j c_j x_j \right)^2  - \left(\sum_j\mu_jx_j  \right)^2\right]}{\sum_j\sigma_j^2x_j^2}
$$
and now I am stuck and don't know what I miss.

I hope somebody can bring ligth into the dark.

Thank you in advance,

T3 K14

Comment: You need to use independence (or at least pairwise independence) of the $c_j$s. I assume they are independent? (If so, what you want is that variancenif sum = sum of variances when the covariance is 0)

Comment: @ClementC. thank you for your helpful answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Independence of $c_j$ is needed.

$(\sum_jc_jx_j)^2=\sum_jx_j^2c_j^2+\sum_j\sum_{i\ne j}x_ix_jc_ic_j$

$(\sum_j\mu_jx_j)^2=\sum_jx_j^2\mu_j^2+\sum_j\sum_{i\ne j}x_ix_j\mu_i\mu_j$

For $i\ne j$, $E(c_ic_j)=\mu_i\mu_j$ (independence) so double sum over $i,j$ is zero.

$E(x_j^2(c_j^2-\mu_j^2))=x_j^2(E(c_j^2)-\mu^2)=x_j^2\sigma_j^2$, so sum over $j$ in the numerator is identical to the denominator.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you for your answer.